# How to query Classes with Object Property in Sparql

Tags: rdf, sparql, ontology, owl, rdfs

Does any one know how to query Classes with Object Property in Sparql?
Assume we have an OWL file which contains follows

```
Human ----(hasPizza)---> Pizzas
```

Human and Pizzas are classes (or concepts). In SPARQL, this query returns nothing:

```
select ?x ?y where {
  ?x hasPizza ?y
}
```

But if I add two individuals (or entities) under those concepts like

```
Human:Jim ----(hasPizza)---> Pizzas:cheesePizza
```

that query will return `?x=Jim` and `?y=cheesePizza`
How can I get `?x=Human` and `?y=Pizza` using SPARQL?

Comment: Could you post the RDF version of your ontology? Classes are not directly linked by properties in OWL, it is usually done via an existential restriction axiom. So open the RDF version of your ontology and look the construct; you can then try to match it with your SPARQL query.

Comment: It sounds much more likely that you have an object property `hasPizza`, the _rdfs:domain_ and _rdfs:range_ of which are `Human` and `Pizzas`, respectively.  This is relatively easy to search for too, though, but it is a distinct task.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Given data like this (in RDF/XML):

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:pizzas="http://example.org/pizzas#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://example.org/pizzas"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/pizzas#Pizza"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://example.org/pizzas#Human"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://example.org/pizzas#hasPizza">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://example.org/pizzas#Human"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://example.org/pizzas#Pizza"/>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://example.org/pizzas#Jim">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://example.org/pizzas#Human"/>
    <pizzas:hasPizza>
      <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://example.org/pizzas#CheesePizza">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://example.org/pizzas#Pizza"/>
      </owl:NamedIndividual>
    </pizzas:hasPizza>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

or the same, in the more readable Turtle:

```
@prefix :        <http://example.org/pizzas#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix pizzas:  <http://example.org/pizzas#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .

pizzas:Jim
      a       pizzas:Human , owl:NamedIndividual ;
      pizzas:hasPizza pizzas:CheesePizza .

pizzas:hasPizza
      a       owl:ObjectProperty ;
      rdfs:domain pizzas:Human ;
      rdfs:range pizzas:Pizza .

pizzas:Human
      a       owl:Class .

pizzas:Pizza
      a       owl:Class .

<http://example.org/pizzas>
      a       owl:Ontology .

pizzas:CheesePizza
      a       pizzas:Pizza , owl:NamedIndividual .
```

notice that the assertion `Jim hasPizza CheesePizza` is one triple in the graph.   The domain and range axioms for the `hasPizza` object property are two triples: `hasPizza rdfs:domain Human` and `hasPizza rdfs:range Pizza`.  SPARQL queries match query patterns against the triples in the graph.  Thus, from a query like:

```
prefix :        <http://example.org/pizzas#>

select ?x ?y where { 
  ?x :hasPizza ?y
}
```

you will get results such as

```
$ arq --data pizzas.ttl --query query.sparql
-----------------------
| x    | y            |
=======================
| :Jim | :CheesePizza |
-----------------------
```

because there is one triple in the graph whose predicate is `:hasPizza`, and that triple has a `:Jim` as the subject, and `:CheesePizza` as the object.  It sounds like you're actually asking for the domain and range of the `:hasPizza` property, which are also easy to retrieve.  Use a query like this:

```
prefix :        <http://example.org/pizzas#>
prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

select ?domain ?range where { 
  :hasPizza rdfs:domain ?domain ;
            rdfs:range ?range .
}
```

and you'll get results like this:

```
$ arq --data pizzas.ttl --query query.sparql
-------------------
| domain | range  |
===================
| :Human | :Pizza |
-------------------
```